# Cannot get the param on first page load

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to apply several background themes for certain pages in my react app. For that my approach is read the page name from the url and according to the page name i'm applying several themes.

I have created a layout to render my components and from there i'm trying to read the page name from the url.

My approach

```
const HomeLayout = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    const activePage = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');
    const gradientPages_type1 = ['consumer_add', 'myprofile', 'nfc_add','evc_detail'];
    const gradientPages_type2 = [''];
    const gradientPages_type3 = ['dashboard']


    return (
        <PrivateRoute {...rest} render={matchProps => (
            <div id="">
                <div className="DefaultLayout mx-auto" id={gradientPages_type1.includes(activePage) ?
                    'bg_gradient' : gradientPages_type2.includes(activePage) ? 'bg_gradient2' : gradientPages_type3.includes(activePage) ?'bg_gradient3':'bg_normal'}>
                    <div className="Header"><Header /></div>
                    <div><Component {...matchProps} /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )} />
    )
};

export default HomeLayout;
```

But the issue i'm facing is i can only get the `activePage` on the second refresh. If i normally navigate through my app i won't be able to get the `activePage` but upon refreshing again i can get the page name. How can i get the `activePage` on the first render itself. I tried making my `HomeLayout` a class and tried to obtain the active page on `componentDidMount`, but still could not get the page name from my url. Is there a solution for this?

My App.js

```
function App() {

  const authenticateUser = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    authenticate() {
      if (token) {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
      } else {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
      }
    }
  };

  return (

    <div>
      {authenticateUser.authenticate()}
      <Switch>
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authenticateUser.isAuthenticated}>
          <LoginLayout path="/" component={Login} exact />
          <LoginLayout path="/register" component={Register} />
          <HomeLayout path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <HomeLayout path="/evc" component={EvcStations} />
          <HomeLayout path="/nfc" component={NfcContainer} />
          <Route component={FourNoteFour} />
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </Switch>
    </div>

  );
}
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Router history={history}><App /></Router></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use react-router-dom with use-react-router library as I do. Just check the documentation and I think you will be able to find a solution.

Comment: @RudolfCicko i'm using react-router-dom. I have updated my question with more code. Can you take a look

Comment: Instead of using `window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');` try to use useReactRouter library.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was i was using my `<AuthContext.Provider value={authenticateUser.isAuthenticated}>` inside my `Switch`. What i had to do was taking the `AuthContext` outside of the Switch and it worked.